# Does CallListener include brackets while returning the number

Tags: android

Does the in built CallListener in Android include brackets if the number has any? For instance take this number - (415)1234567, will it be shown as 415123457 or will be shown as it is with the brackets ? 
I wont be able to test this on my own since my country has no brackets in the phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simply may not! But if you feel doubt on this you can add one more line of code to Strip those kind of Separators using [`stripSeparators`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#stripSeparators(java.lang.String)).

```
PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(yourPhoneNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I might use Regex instead of this method you mentioned to decrease the system overlay.

Comment: @MichaelScott You are welcome, But remember the "+" sign as well which may not be stripped with above method.

Comment: Will regex the + as well as the other symbols which may come in a phone number.